# Why can you initialize a string pointer as a string literal, but not as an array?

Tags: c, string

Strings can be initialized with a string literal

```
char word1[] = "abc";
```

or as a char array with a null terminator.

```
char word2[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
```

Instead of writing `word1[]`, word1 can also be written with a pointer notation

```
char *word1 = "abc";
```

However, when trying to write word2 with a pointer notation

```
char *word2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
```

it shows me a bunch of warnings, such as

> warning: excess elements in scalar initializer char
> *word2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};

and when I run the program, I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Why is that? Why can you write `char *word = "abc"` but not `char *word = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}` ?

Comment: Try a [compound literal](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5): `char *word2 = (char[4]){'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};`

Comment: @pmg Thanks very much for that pointer.  Compound literals are still a bit too newfangled for me to remember.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why can you initialize a string pointer as a string literal, but not as an array?

Because `{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}` is not an array; it is a list of values to put in the thing being initialized.

The syntax `{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}` does not stand for an array in C. People see it being used to initialize arrays, but, when used in that way, it is just a list of values. It could also be used to initialize a structure, because it is just listing values to put into the thing being initialized. It is not, by itself, an array.

In `char *word2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};`, it does not make sense to initialize `word2` with the values `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, and `'\0'`. It is just one pointer and should be initialized with one value. Giving a list of four values to initialize one thing does not make sense.

In `char *word2 = "abc";`, `"abc"` is not a list of values. It is a string literal. A string literal defines a static array that is filled with the characters of the string. And then the string literal is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, and it is this pointer that is used to initialize `word2`.

So `char *word2 = "abc";` does two things: The string literal defines an array, and the initialization sets `word2` to point to the first element of that array. In contrast, in `char *word2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};`, there is nothing to define an array; the list of values is just a list of values.

Comparing this to array initializations, in `char word2[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};`, the array is initialized with a list of values, which is fine. However, in `char word1[] = "abc";`, something special happens. C 2018 6.7.9 14 says we can initialize an array of character type with a string literal, and the characters of the string will be used to initialize the elements of the array.

Answer (score 5):

There's no fundamental reason for this -- it's just the way the language was originaly defined.

The basic syntax for array initialization is

```
type array[] = {value, value, value};
```

The basic syntax for pointer initialization is

```
type *pointer = value;
```

But then we have string literals.  And it turns out that, deep down inside, the compiler does two almost completely different things with string literals.

If you say

```
char array[] = "string";
```

the compiler treats it just about exactly as if you had said

```
char array[] = { 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0' };
```

But if you say

```
char *p = "string";
```

the compiler does something quite different.  It quietly creates an array for you, containing the string, more or less as if you had written

```
char __hidden_unnamed_array[] = "string";
char *p = __hidden_unnamed_array;
```

But the point -- the answer to your question -- is that the compiler does this special thing only for string literals.  In the original definition of C, at least, there was no way to use the `{value, value, value}` syntax to create a hidden, unnamed array that you could do something else with.  The `{value, value, value}` syntax was only defined as working as the direct initializer for an explicitly-declared array.

As @pmg mentions in a comment, however, newer versions of C have a new syntax, the *compound literal*, which *does* let you, basically, "use the `{value, value, value}` syntax to create a hidden, unnamed array to do something else with".  So you can in fact write

```
char *word2 = (char[]){'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
```

and this works just fine.  It works in other contexts, too: for example, you can say things like

```
printf("%s\n", (char[]){'d', 'e', 'f', '\0'});
```

Going back to a side question you asked: when you wrote

```
char *word2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
```

the compiler said to itself, "Wait a minute, `word2` is one thing, but the initializer has four things.  So I'll throw away three, and warn the programmer that I'm doing so."  It then did the equivalent of

```
char *word2 = {'a'};
```

and if you later tried something like

```
printf("%s", word2);
```

you got a crash when `printf` tried to access address 0x00000061.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the type of the initializer must match the type of what is being initialized.

This works:

```
char *word1 = "abc";
```

Because a string constant has type array of `char` and such an array decays to type `char *` when used in an expression or initialization, so this matches the declared type.

This works:

```
char word2[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
```

Because an array of `char` is being initialized with an initializer list of characters (technically they have type `int` but are converted to `char`).

This gives a warning:

```
char *word2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
```

Because an initializer list is being used to initialize a type which is not an array or struct.

And this is OK:

```
char word1[] = "abc";
```

Because the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) specifically allows initializing a `char` array with a string literal, as specified in section 6.7.9p14:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
> literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.
> Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null
> character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size)
> initialize the elements of the array.